# internet explorer doesn't show print dialog after windows update

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jasper-reports, adobe-reader

I have an application with Java 1.6 and JSF 1.2. PDF documents are printed in this application. The problem is that after a windows update, the printer window is not displayed in internet explorer 11.

```
   JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, 
       "this.print({bUI: true,bSilent: false,bShrinkToFit: true});");
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
    exporter.exportReport();
```

If I program it to do a silent print, without showing the printer dialog box, it works perfectly.

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, 
"var pp = this.getPrintParams();pp.interactive = 
 pp.constants.interactionLevel.silent;this.print(pp);");
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
exporter.exportReport();
```

I need to be able to display the print dialog box.

After many tests I have seen a possible solution (although it does not serve as a definitive solution). If I uncheck the option to enable protected mode at startup, in the adobe acrobat reader menu, if it works, but it does not serve as a final solution in the production environment

---

After trying various configurations, I have seen that the problem is solved in two steps. The first step is to disable safe mode in Adobe Reader and the second step is to also remove safe mode in Internet Explorer 11. There are two changes that I cannot ask the user for. Is there a way to do it using code?

Comment: Can you please inform us, which OS build you are using and after which update this issue occurred? Does this code showing the print dialog before this update? Any error or warning message in the console of the browser? Please try to provide this information may help to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: - OS. Windows 10 PRO 64bits
- Version: 19041.388
- Before the last update the application worked correctly.
- No errors or warmings into Internet Explorer Console or application logs

Comment: I am not sure which safe mode you are talking about for the IE browser. Generally when a user launches the IE with '-extoff' then IE get launched in a safe mode. This mode will turn off any program add-ons and some extensions not required for the basic running of the browser. There is no specific option for the safe mode in the IE UI. If possible please provide detailed information about it.

Answer (score 0):

I try to check the update history of [July 14, 2020—KB4565503 (OS Build 19041.388)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4565503/windows-10-update-kb4565503) update.

It is mentioned in the docs that some changes has been done in print functionality to fix some other issues.

I noticed that new update is available. [July 31, 2020—KB4568831 (OS Build 19041.423) Preview](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4568831/windows-10-update-kb4568831)

In which it is mentioned that some print functionality related issue has been fixed.

[image]

I suggest try to install this update and check whether it helps to fix the said issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but after installing the update it did not work either

Comment: If possible for you can you share the sample project that can produce the issue on our end. We can try to check and test it. You can remove the personal or confidential information from it. Thanks for your understanding.